# I need to write an automation script in Postman to validate that GET would bring only "account" that has code1 & code2 in one record

Tags: postman

I am new to Postman and I am trying to write automated validation for GET

I have multiple records saved in DB and I need to write an automation script in  Postman to validate that GET would bring  only "account" that has code1 & code2  in one record like in an example  below

```
"account": [
             {    {
                    "system":" 'system1",
                     "code": "code1"                  
                  },
                  {
                    "system": "sytem1",
                    "code": "code2"                    
                  }]

Tried  var obj = responseData.entry[i];
       tests["Specialty"]= obj.account[0].code ===  "code1"&"code2";
        and it is not working
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
var obj = responseData.entry[i];
var account;
if (obj.account[0].code ===  "code1" && obj.account[1].code = "code2"){
    account = obj.account;
}
tests["Specialty", account] = true;
```

Hope this helps